# How to call team.accessLogs Slack API?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I need to download access logs from all users.

My user has the `Workspace Owner` role.

I used Slack CLI to generate a service token `xoxp-***-***-***`

I'm using this command to try the API:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer xoxp-***-***-***" "https://slack.com/api/team.accessLogs"
```

But I'm getting this response:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "missing_scope",
    "needed": "admin",
    "provided": "identify,channels:read,groups:read,team:read,users:read,hosting:write,hosting:read,datastore:read,datastore:write,app_configurations:read,app_configurations:write,apps.requests:write,triggers:read,triggers:write"
}
```

[It seems that my user lacks from some permission](https://api.slack.com/scopes/admin) (`admin` scope), but I am a `Workspace Owner` so I don't understand what is missing.

Additional info: I have the `Pro plan` subscription.